# Histogram computational efficiency

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to plot a 2 GB matrix using MATLAB `hist` on a computer with 4 GB RAM. The operation is taking hours. Are there ways to increase the performance of the computation, by pre-sorting the data, pre-determining bin sizes, breaking the data into smaller groups, deleting the raw data as the data is added to bins, etc?

Also, after the data is plotted, I need to adjust the binning to ensure the curve is smooth. This requires starting over and re-binning the raw data. I assume the strategy involving the least computation would be to first bin the data using very small bins and then manipulate the bin size of the output, rather than re-binning the raw data. What is the best way to adjust bin sizes post-binning (assuming the bin sizes can only grow and not shrink)?

Comment: To answer the part about re-binning: If you want to halve the number of bins (for example), then simply add every other bin to its neighbour (`newbins = oldbins(1:2:end) + oldbins(2:2:end)`.  Assuming you have a sane number of bins, that should be very quick.

Comment: Do you really need to plot the histogram for all 2 GB of data? I mean, the point of a graphical display is to extract important info from the way it looks, and after a certain point, changes from including more data will be indistinguishable to the human eye. I suggest plotting every 10th, or 100th, data point, or something. Find some level where the fidelity of the plot is good but the computation time is short, especially when you're trying to quickly plot, check the binning, then re-plot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like answers to StackOverflow Questions of the form "well even though you asked how to do X, you don't really want to do X, you really want to do Y, so here's a solution to Y"

But that's what i am going to do here. I think such an answer is justified in this rare instance becuase the answer below is in accord with sound practices in statistical analysis and because it avoids the current problem in front of you which is crunching 4 GB of datda.

If you want to represent the distribution of a population using a non-parametric density estimator, and you wwish to avoid  poor computational performance, a ***kernel density estimator (KDE)*** *will do the job far better than a histogram*.

To begin with, there's a clear preference for KDEs versus histograms among the majority of academic and practicing statisticians. Among the numerous texts on this topic, ne that i think is particularly good is *[An introduction to kernel density estimation](http://www.mvstat.net/tduong/research/seminars/seminar-2001-05/)* )

### Reasons why KDE is preferred to histogram

- the *shape of a histogram is strongly influenced by the choice of
  total number of bins*; yet there is no authoritative technique for
  calculating or even estimating a suitable value. (Any doubts about this, just plot a histogram from some data, then watch the entire shape of the histogram change as you adjust the number of bins.)
- the *shape of the histogram is strongly influenced by the choice of
  location of the bin edges*.
- a histogram gives a density estimate that is *not smooth*.

KDE eliminates completely histogram properties 2 and 3. Although KDE doesn't produce a density estimate with discrete bins, an analogous parameter, "bandwidth" must still be supplied.

To calculate and plot a KDE, you need to pass in two parameter values along with your data:

*kernel function*: the most common options (all available in the MATLAB kde function) are: uniform, triangular, biweight, triweight, Epanechnikov, and normal. Among these, gaussian (normal) is probably most often used.

*bandwith*: the choice of value for bandwith will almost certainly have a huge effect on the quality of your KDE. Therefore, sophisticated computation platforms like MATLAB, R, etc. include utility functions (e.g., rusk function or MISE) to estimate bandwith given oother parameters.

---

**KDE in MATLAB**

***kde.m*** is the function in MATLAB that implementes KDE:

```
[h, fhat, xgrid] = kde(x, 401);
```

Notice that bandwith and kernel are not supplied when calling kde.m. For bandwitdh: kde.m wraps a function for bandwidth selection; and for the kernel function, gaussian is used.

---

*But will using KDE in place of a histogram solve or substantially eliminate the very slow performance given your 2 GB dataset?*

It certainly should.

In your Question, you stated that the lagging performance occurred during plotting. A KDE does not require mapping of thousands (missions?) of data points a symbol, color, and specific location on a canvas--instead it plots a single smooth line. And because the entire data set doesn't need to be rendered one point at a time on the canvas, they don't need to be stored (in memory!) while the plot is created and rendered.